# Spring Boot sporadically fails to find classpath resource

Tags: spring-boot, fatjar

When starting from the IDE, it works. Starting the fat jar from command line also used to work, but since recently I get the following error:

```
Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.io.File (caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not retrieve file for class path resource [api-jwt-dev_keystore.p12]: class path resource [api-jwt-dev_keystore.p12] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app/bin/myapp-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/api-jwt-dev_keystore.p12)
```

this is my application.yml:

```
app:
  zone-id: "UTC"
    jwt:
      sign-key-store-file: classpath:api-jwt-dev_keystore.p12
```

I extracted the fat-jar and the file seems to be there.